# Can't seem to increment a nested value in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I can't seem to increment a nested value in mongoose.  I have tried multiple revisions that I have found online and none seem to work.  I am using mongodb version 3.2 and mongoose 4.9.5.

This project is a forum.  There is a thread with a "posts" property which is an array.  Each post has a "like" property which has a "users" property for each person who liked that post, and a count property that should increment with each update. Here is my model:

```
const threadSchema = mongoose.Schema({  
title: {type: String, required: true},
date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
author: {type: String, required: true},
content: {type: String},
posts: [{
    content: {type: String, required: true},
    user: {type: String, required: true},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    likes: {
        users: [String],
        count: {type: Number, default: 0}
    },      
    comments: [{
        comment: {type: String},
        user: {type: String},
        created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        likes: {type: Number, default: 0}
    }]
}]
});
```

And here is my update code.  It is pushing to the posts.likes.users array just fine but wont increment:

```
Threads.findOneAndUpdate({"posts._id": req.body.postId}, {"$push": {"posts.$.likes.users": user}}, {$inc: {"posts.$.likes.count": 1}})
```

I have also tried these versions:

```
 {"$inc": {"posts.likes.count": 1}}
 {"$inc": {"posts.$.likes.count": 1}}
 {"$inc": {"posts.$.likes.$.count": 1}}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems as though I cant do both edits in the same line. Separating them seemed to do the trick.

```
Threads.findOneAndUpdate({"posts._id": req.body.postId}, 
{"$push": {"posts.$.likes.users": user}})
.exec()
.then((post) => {
    //some stuff
})

Threads.findOneAndUpdate({"posts._id": req.body.postId}, 
({"posts._id": req.body.postId}, 
{$inc: {"posts.$.likes.count": 1}})
.exec()
.then((post) => {
    // some other stuff
})
```